# What is the difference between Python decorators and the decorator pattern?

Tags: python, design-patterns, decorator

What is the difference between “Python decorators” and the “decorator pattern”?

When should I use Python decorators, and when should I use the decorator pattern?

I'm looking for examples of Python decorators and the decorator pattern accomplishing same.

**@AcceptedAnswer**

I know that [Jakob Bowyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8328867/708764) is valid. Yet it's Srikar's answer that made me understand why.

After Srikar's answer, and studying the given resources, I've written this example, so I can visualize and understand Python decorators and the decorator pattern.

I must **disagree** with Srikar's "*Python decorators are not an implementation of the decorator pattern*". After what I've learned, **I'm strongly convinced that Python decorators are an implementation of the decorator pattern.** Just not in the classic way.

**Also**, I need to add that, despite the fact that Srikar said "*Python decorators add functionality to functions and methods at definition time*", **you can easily use Python decorators at run time**.

Yet, I still mark Srikar's answer as accepted, because it helped me understand [**the implementation**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) **of the decorator pattern in Python**.

```
"""
Testing Python decorators against the decorator pattern
"""
def function(string):
    return string

def decorator(wrapped):
    def wrap(string):
        # Assume that this is something useful
        return wrapped(string.upper())
    return wrap

def method_decorator(wrapped):
    def wrap(instance, string):
        # Assume that this is something useful
        return wrapped(instance, string.upper())
    return wrap

@decorator
def decorated_function(string):
    print('! '.join(string.split(' ')))

class Class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def something_useful(self, string):
        return string

class Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped
    def something_useful(self, string):
        string = '! '.join(string.split(' '))
        return self.wrapped().something_useful(string)

    @method_decorator
    def decorated_and_useful(self,string):
        return self.something_useful(string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
    print(function(string))                  # Plain function
    print(decorator(function)(string))       # Python decorator at run time
    print(decorated_function(string))        # Python decorator at definition time
    a = Class()
    print(a.something_useful(string))        # Plain method
    b = Decorator(Class)
    print(b.something_useful(string))        # Decorator pattern
    print(b.decorated_and_useful(string))    # Python decorator decorated the decorator pattern
```

Comment: @Srikar is correct. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3118929/146792)'s another SO question that you might find interesting though!

Comment: @Srikar, I can't accept Snswer that do not resolve problem descriped in Question, sorry, but most of proposed solutions in my questions are not working.

Comment: FWIW, according to the Wikipedia article on [Python decorators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators): "Despite the name, Python decorators are not an implementation of the decorator pattern". It goes on to explain why.

Comment: Thanks @apcelent. This might help understand the topic to whoever gets here ;)

Comment: Srikar's answer is absolutely right.  Decorators are no for run-time modification.  My answer adds a little nuance, but his answer his answer is the best.   https://www.codementor.io/@sheena/advanced-use-python-decorators-class-function-du107nxsv

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Decorator Pattern** - In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows behaviour to be added to an existing object dynamically. The decorator pattern can be used to extend (decorate) the functionality of a certain object at run-time, independently of other instances of the same class, provided some groundwork is done at design time.

**Decorators in Python** - Despite the name, Python decorators are not an implementation of the decorator pattern. The decorator pattern is a design pattern used in statically typed object-oriented programming languages to allow functionality to be added to objects at run time; Python decorators add functionality to functions and methods at definition time, and thus are a higher-level construct than decorator-pattern classes.

The decorator pattern itself is trivially implementable in Python, because the language is duck typed, and so is not usually considered as such. So in Python a decorator is any callable Python object that is used to modify a function, method or class definition.

I hope I made the difference clear. Just in case you did not completely understand, please go through these links. You will come out more than clear at the end of it -

- *[How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)*
- *[Implementing the decorator pattern in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118929/implementing-the-decorator-pattern-in-python)*
- *[What is the difference between using decorators and extending a sub class by inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229287/what-is-the-difference-between-using-decorators-and-extending-a-sub-class-by-inh)*
- *[Python Class Decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681953/python-class-decorator)*
- *[PyWiki - Python Decorators - A detailed discourse](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators)*
- *[Python Decorators Made Easy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cpdecor/index.html)*
- *[Source 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) & [source 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators)*

Comment: "The decorator pattern itself is trivially implementable in Python, because the language is duck typed, and so is not usually considered as such. So in Python a decorator is any callable Python object that is used to modify a function, method or class definition." In Python, functions are objects; and a Python  decorator (with `@` syntax) is extending the functionality of that function object, independently of other functions (i.e., instances of the built-in `function` type). How is that not an implementation of the Decorator pattern?

Answer (score 4):

The difference is this:

(a) Python decorators are tied to an existing method and change the behavior of that method.  Example:

```
@modifyBehavior
def original(myString):
    print myString
```

The behavior of original is overwritten.  You can't use this to add a new functionality.

(b) Decorator pattern is about polymorphism.  In your sample code above, the behavior of Decorator.something_useful is overwritten.  The original method is lost.  It's not really decorator pattern.  You should be looking to enhance or add functionality, not replace a method.  You should ensure that a.something_useful(string) returns the same thing as b.something_useful(string).  In fact, in decorator pattern you would typically replace the original object.  Here is what I mean:

```
class Class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def something_useful(self, string):
        return string

class Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped
    def withUnderscores(self, string):
        return '_'.join(string.split(' '))
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._wrapped, name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
    obj = Class()
    print('Original: ', obj.something_useful(string))
    #This has no underscore function.  Use decorator to add.
    obj = Decorator(obj)
    print('Replaced spaces: ', obj.withUnderscores(string))
    print('Original still works: ', obj.something_useful(string))
```

You can have several decorators to add functionality.  This allows you to add only what you need when you need it.  More reading: [GoF](https://springframework.guru/gang-of-four-design-patterns/decorator-pattern/)